# Path to SourceTree broken in last update

Tags: git

I recently upgraded SourceTree to the latest version, and now I can't check out branches in it from BitBucket (via the **Check out in SourceTree** option in a drop down that's available after creating a branch) anymore. (Our Bitbucket repositories are located on site, rather than on Bitbucket.org.) The last upgrade seems to have moved SourceTree.exe from its old location, but a search of the hard drive comes up empty. Does anyone know what the new path to it/command for running it is so that I can update that setting in my browser?

The old path/command that was set up in my browser was:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Atlassian\SourceTree.exe" -url "%1"

however, the the Atlassian folder does not even exist anymore under either of the Program Files folders (and neither does SourceTree.exe exist if that empty search is any indication). They seem to have set up some kind of indirect way of running the new version of SourceTree; the Target for the shortcut is now:

C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\SourceTree\Update.exe --processStart "SourceTree.exe"

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had is that the [program launched by the] shortcut quit working.  It appears to start something (spinning icon) but then just goes away.  I subsequently discovered, at the path you posted,

> \AppData\Local\SourceTree\

a copy of the non-working exe file.  You will also find folders for each update installed.  Each folder has a SourceTree.exe file within.  I chose one of those to run. I don't think it's the appropriate way to run the program, but the application does end up running.   The reason I say inappropriate is that a window pops up and then closes before I can read it; it has a progress bar; I get the impression it is installing itself every time I run it.

Comment: On the other hand, git from the command line just works.